# Separate javascript from html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with javascript and multiple form(s) requesting user input. As the webpage is getting too busy, I am attempting to separate the javascript to it's own page.

Sample code of my page,

```html
<body <script type="application/javascript">
    function Opencorporates(selection){ window.open("https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q="+selection.value+"&format=xml") }
    </script>

    <form onsubmit="Opencorporates(query)">
        <h2>Opencorporates:</h2> <input type="text" placeholder="Company Check" name="query"><input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script src="javascript_samples.js"></script>

</body>
```

My attempt at calling JavaScript is unsuccessful.

I have saved the javascripts `javascript_samples.js`, but I am unable to get the query to work.

```js
function Opencorporates(selection) {

    window.open("https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q=" + selection.value + "&format=xml");

}
```

I am not sure how to call the saved script from the webpage.

```html
<body>
    <form name="search" onsubmit="return Opencorporates();">
        <input type="text" placeholder="OPenCorpo" name="query">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
    <script src="javascript_samples.js"></script>
</body>
```

My level of experience with javascript is limited/beginner. A "dummies guide" style reply would be appreciated.

Comment: `I am unable to get the query to work.` - errors in console or something?

Comment: Can you include your javascript_samples.js file please?

Comment: You need to check the developer console (hit f12) of your browser and see if the file is being loaded and what your errors are. You can find more specific instructions by searching for "Debugging javascript tutorial"

Comment: Hi Brian, The javascript_samples.js contains one function   i.e.                                
      function Opencorporates(selection){

window.open("https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q="+selection.value+"&format=xml");

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer (kinda)**

Okay, after doing some digging I found the problem. However I am going to hold onto the solution and instead give you some advice; which is learn how to debug your code. This is an integral part of the coding process. To debug Html and Javascript, the chrome developer tools are your best friend. Please spend some time reading through the tutorials and reading through the [chrome debugger documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/). Once you've got a basic understanding of how these tools work, you should be able to solve this bug as well as other bugs in the future.

**For Consideration**

There is another bug in this code I want you to consider. Its not a bug that is obvious, but it is a bug that could cause your employer or client (whomever this code is for) some damage. Consider this line:

`window.open("https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q="+selection.value+"&format=xml")`

Notice that the `+selection.value+` means that whatever a user types into the textbox gets output raw into the query. This means a motivated hacker could use a hacking technique called [Cross Site Scripting or XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)). I recommend reading about about the [OWASP top 10 security vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013) which has to do with web security.

Comment: Thanks for push in right direction. Looking at Chrome debugger as we speak.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<body>
<form name="search" onsubmit = "return Opencorporates();">
        <input type="text" placeholder="OPenCorpo" name="query">
        <input type = "submit" name="submit" value = "submit" ></form>
<script src="~/javascript_samples.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: And why `~/` (I assume current user dir) should help?

Comment: open the console, see the source js file if there is no problem